# Load operation failed for query x. the remote server returned an error: notfound

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I published a silverlight application with wcf ria service to my local host on windows 7 (IIS7).but when i run application in browser ,my silverlight application can not connect to wcf ria service and i receive the following error:

> load operation failed for query x. the remote server returned an
>   error: notfound

how can i fix this problem?!!!

Comment: Are you sure your connection strings in the Web.config and App.config are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Not Found' error returned by IIS is something of a misnomer.  Many times it masks over something else that happened and thus hides the true error.

One such instance of this is when the amount of information returned by the query exceeds IIS's limit of how much information it can return (the default for IIS 7 is something like 4 meg).  This will result in the 'Not Found' error.  To diagnose this condition, change your service so that it returns only a single record guaranteed to be less than 4 meg in size.  If this is the case, you can change the IIS default, or change your data load strategy (the latter is preferable).

Other conditions can be diagnosed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try attaching a debugger to the method you're calling in the service. There is probably some error happening which [comes back as NotFound](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/146331/325799.aspx). Also, make sure you've enabled Silverlight debugging in the properties of the website project.

Answer (score 0):

Please enter This URL in Browser

"http://Your Site Address/FolderName(s)/MyApp-Web-DishViewDomainService.svc

Service name is  full name of service replace dot with dash
for example if your domainclass is  mynamespace.mydomainclass 
service address is mynamespace-mydomainclass.svc

the browser return error causes your problem
if error is not found check web.config setting
otherwise pls write  your problem

Answer (score 0):

a problem is possible to be a number of record and change maxItemsInObjectGraph

Comment: Does this answer the question?